# django template slow rendering

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

my sql querset  : 109 queryset in 20.3ms
but the total time rendering is 3 seconds

```
          {% for fooo in degray %}
              {% for foo in data %}
                {% for foor in data_list %}
                  {% if fooo.id|cut:" " == foo.withdegrey_id|cut:" " and fooo|cut:" " == foor.name|cut:" " %}
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="1" >{{ foo.percontage }} %</td>
                        <td colspan="1" > {{ foo.date }}  </td>
                        <td colspan="1"  >{{ foo.nomberhodor  }}</td>
                        <td colspan="1"  >{{ foo.nomberesteda  }}</td>
                        <td colspan="1">{{ foor.nomberetud__sum  }}</td>
                        <td colspan="1">{{ foor.name  }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

is useing a lot loop in template with condition make rendering slow ??

Comment: What is the `{% if fooo.id|cut:" " == foo.withdegrey_id|cut:" " and fooo|cut:" " == foor.name|cut:" " %}` doing? Try to filter at the *database side*, not in the template.

Comment: cuz i am new in django i was try to get all degray  and datadegry and use condition to make it render or no